# CSV Output to file Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I'm trying to print certain values into a CSV from a list I'm passing through.  Here is my function:

````
current = datetime.datetime.now() #defining datetime for use in function
def write_csv(custody_parts):
    with open((current.strftime("%m_%d_%y_%H_%M_%S")) + '.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
         csvfile = io.StringIO()
         fieldnames = ['serial', 'user', 'time']
         writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, extrasaction='ignore', fieldnames=fieldnames)
         writer.writeheader()
         writer.writerows(custody_parts)
         csvfile.getvalue()
         print(csvfile.getvalue())
         return(csvfile.getvalue())```
````

Then I call it with the list I'm trying to pass through:

```
write_csv(parts)
```

and it creates the file:  `06_06_18_12_13_53.csv`

and prints to the screen:

> serial,user,time
>
> serial1,user1,date1
>
> serial2,user2,date2
>
> serial3,user3,date3

but the file it creates is `empty`, so it isn't writing to the file it is creating.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks ~

EDIT:

I ended up going with this instead:

```
def write_csv(custody_parts):
current = datetime.datetime.now()
    with open((current.strftime("%m_%d_%y_%H_%M_%S")) + '.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
        custodywriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
         custodywriter.writerow(['serial', 'user', 'time'])
         for i in custody_parts:
             x = [i["serial"],i["user"],i["time"]]
             custodywriter.writerow(x)
         custodywriter.writerow(["End of Report"])
```

Comment: try commenting the line `csvfile = io.StringIO()` where you're replacing your file by a memory buffer

Comment: I did try that, but that didn't help. I ended up abandoning DictWriter and going with just writer.

Comment: didn't help how? it works fine for me